# Can the jQuery ajax success function hold 'undefined' as data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-ajax

In the process of adding unit test coverage to existing javascript code we've encountered a case which we cannot seem to cover well, namely the code that checks for the callback's data to be undefined:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: someUrl,
    success: function(data) {
     if (typeof data === "undefined") {
        // *** How do I cover this line with jasmine? ***
     }
    },
    error: function () {
      // handle errors
    }
});
```

One of the possible answers would be that we cannot test this line, as `data` passed to the success function by jQuery.ajax cannot be undefined. Is that the case?

[The reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) mentions the data type of the passed `data` to be [Anything](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Anything), but I'm not sure if this does or does not mean `data` could be undefined, and if we could test the branch.

> **success**
>
> ```
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
> ```

Comment: Why don't you create a quick example and test it?

Comment: if the URL called simply returns an empty reply it'd be an empty string, not undefined - since you're expecting json, that'd mean the jQuery function would've croaked on that, so the ERROR handler would be responsible. See the result on your console if you enter: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(undefined))

Comment: @flowtron between the lines I'm reading the implication that the data in the success function is a JSON.parsed 'thing'. Is that the case? Can I expect that to always be the case for jQuery?

Comment: @Spork yes you can expect that as long as you define `dataType`. Either jQuery will call the error function if the data returned fails to parse as JSON or the data is valid JSON and the success function will be called.

Comment: In which case if it was valid json it would never be undefined.

Comment: The answer to my question would then be that the docs are unnecessarily broad with 'Anything', and this implementation detail will never change -- jQuery uses JSON.parse and JSON.parse can only return an Object.

Comment: jQuery *only* uses json parse because of your dataType configuration.  That's an important note.